# How to generate an image using C code

Tags: c, bmp

The function below simply serves html when it is called, however

```
void generateHTML (int socket) {
   char* message;

   // Sends HTTP response header

   message = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                "\r\n";
   printf ("about to send=> %s\n", message);
   write (socket, message, strlen (message));

   message = "<HTML><BODY><P>Hello World.</P></BODY></HTML>\n";
   printf ("about to send=> %s\n", message);
   write (socket, message, strlen (message));   
}
```

My output on the web browser would by a simple Hello World message. However, I want to change it so that it will display a bitmap image instead. Let's use a 1x1 red pixel as our bmp.

I've modified this function so far by:

```
void generateHTML (int socket) {
   char* message;

   // Sends HTTP response header

   message = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                "Content-Type: image/bmp\r\n"
                "Content-Length: ???WTF???\r\n";
   printf ("about to send=> %s\n", message);
   write (socket, message, strlen (message));

   message = "BMF8\n";
   printf ("about to send=> %s\n", message);
   write (socket, message, strlen (message));   

   message = " "; //bmp file data goes here.
   printf ("about to send=> %s\n", message);
   write (socket, message, strlen (message));   
}
```

Quoting from Dan's answer, the data in hex looks like:

```
0000000: 424d 3a00 0000 0000 0000 3600 0000 2800  BM:.......6...(.
0000010: 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 0100 1800 0000  ................
0000020: 0000 0400 0000 130b 0000 130b 0000 0000  ................
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000                 ..........
```

However, I simply cannot place that inside the quotation marks. How would I do this?

Comment: it's not that simple, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: I've read the wiki article but I'm still having trouble with it. Just need someone to post an example of what a single black bmp pixel will look like.

Comment: @meiryo: @jcomeau_ictx is right. That's not trivial. If you have no time or simply don't want try to understand the format specification, the try to search some useful libraries that can perform the job for you.

Comment: If there are any tutorials you can suggest for me, that allows a web server to serve up a bmp file that would be great, thanks.

Comment: @meiryo: please try always to tell us when it's homework. By the way, in this case you need to read carefully the BMP specifications and implement what you need

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to SO. Can someone give me a break down of bmp header?

Comment: I'm going to do a complete rewrite of this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is an xxd dump of a 1x1 black windows bmp image:

```
0000000: 424d 3a00 0000 0000 0000 3600 0000 2800  BM:.......6...(.
0000010: 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 0100 1800 0000  ................
0000020: 0000 0400 0000 130b 0000 130b 0000 0000  ................
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000                 ..........
```

Comment: Okay, 42 4D is BM to tell that it's a legitimate bmp file. I'm not so sure about 3A and so forth. Sorry if I'm not making any sense, kinda stressed out at the moment.

Comment: Dan, you beat me to it, so +1, but I didn't see your answer till after I'd already figured out the convert command and dumped my bmp file. what can I say, except great minds think alike :^)

Comment: @jcomeau Okay I've rewritten the question for more clarity at what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

expanding on what @Dan D. said, you can use ImageMagick's "convert" command on a Linux (or possibly Windows also) box to convert raw data to an image. I tested with .png, you'll have to test the output on Windows yourself:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ echo -en "\0000" | convert -size 1x1 -depth 8 gray:- /tmp/1black.bmp
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ xxd /tmp/1black.bmp 
0000000: 424d 3a00 0000 0000 0000 3600 0000 2800  BM:.......6...(.
0000010: 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 0100 1800 0000  ................
0000020: 0000 0400 0000 120b 0000 120b 0000 0000  ................
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000                 ..........
```

Answer (score 0):

To print it out you need to create an array
e.g. unsigned char bmp[] ={
and fill this part here with hexadecimal above. However because it is in hexadecimal you need to add 0x to the front of each pair of numbers.
E.g.
0x42, 0x4d
Etc.
This can just be included in the {} brackets.
E.g. 
`unsigned char bmp[] ={
    0x42, 0x4d, 0x....
}`
then just send this through the socket using the write function.
write (socket, bmp, sizeof(bmp));